# WindowsService.OnStop()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I wrote a service in C#, and I overrode the function `OnStop`.

Will this function be called when I restart the service, or only when I stop it?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  Just 1 log statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when you restart the service is called

```
Stop()
```

and then :

```
Start()
```

### The “OnStop” event handler

The “OnStop” event handler is being triggered when the EventLogger Service is being stopped or restarted.

Comment: thank, and when I shut down the compurt, does the Onstop wii be called too? or only the OnShutdown()

Comment: Yes it is called OnStop also at the system shutdown.